# webpack configuration completely scrambled with babel-loader 8

Tags: babel-loader

contradictory documentation (use of presets), traps= contradictory error messages (@babel/preset-es2015 vs babel-preset-es2-15) and more. Ugly.

Where do I find definitive documentation to get out of this trap?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Mostly a matter of updating .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react"
  ]
}
```

and of course updating modules

tip: try npx update-babel